# What is Business Objects Enterprise Java SDK?

Tags: java, spring, jakarta-ee, business-objects-sdk

First, I'm sorry if my questions seems to be a noob question. I'm investigating the jars in our lib folder and found these jars:

- `jrcerom.jar`
- `rasapp.jar`
- `rascore.jar`
- `ReportTemplate.jar`
- `Serialization.jar`
- `webreporting-core.jar`

Upon researching, it seems that these jars came from what they called **Business Objects Enterprise Java SDK**.

- What is **Business Objects Enterprise Java SDK**?
- Is it not a part of the normal Java SDK distribution?
- What does it do?

I also saw on some websites that those jars seems to be needed to use Crystal Report. But we don't have any Crystal Report on our web application. Any idea what it's for?

Some info which I'm not sure if useful: *We are using Spring3 for our web application and we're running it on Tomcat.*

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Business_Objects

Comment: Thanks, BalusC! I thought Business Objects Enterprise is an official API from Java.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at this forum topic, specifically the 3rd post from the top (the one that lists the JARs for Business Objects):

http://www.forumtopics.com/busobj/viewtopic.php?p=417793

Also take a look at SAP / Crystal Reports Business Objects:

http://devlibrary.businessobjects.com/BusinessObjectsXIR2SP2/en/devsuite.htm

Comment: Hi! Thanks for the reply! I've already seen the first link you gave me. That's were I found out that the jars are from Business Objects Enterprise Java SDK. Does it mean that these jars are specifically for SAP and Crystal Report?

Comment: @Arci I would recommend using an unzip utility and looking at the package structure of the JARs.  That should give you an idea if they are specific for SAP/Crystal Report, or if they are generic framework JARs.

Comment: Thanks, Philip! Upon checking the jars, I think it's really for Crystal Report. Their package names includes `crystaldecisions`.